# Minimize trace subject to nonconvex inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $a_1≥a_2^2≥1$, solve the following problem

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} X\\X\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\\\text{subject to} & \mathrm{det}X\geq a_1,\\&\frac{\mathrm{det}X}{\mathrm{det}X-X_{11}}(X_{22}-1)\geq a_2,\\&X>0.\end{array}

If we assume $X$ is diagonal, then $\mathrm{tr}X=2\sqrt{a_1}$. ($x_1=x_2=\sqrt{a_1}$). I wonder whether this is an optimal?

Help me please to simplify the problem. If you have an idea on how to reformulate this problem for CVX will be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is symmetric, we may write this as
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}
$$
we have $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=a+c$ and $\det A=ac-b^2$, so the optimization problem is of the form
\begin{align}
\min&\quad a+c\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad ac-b^2\geqslant a_1\\
&\quad \frac{(ac-b^2)(c-1)}{ac-b^2-a}\geqslant a_2\\
&\quad a,b,c\geqslant 0.
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to solve this, but you may want to look into the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will do it! By the way, $X$ is symmetric positive definite

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the fact that $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: Initially, I tried to follow this way. But I had problem with rewriting second inequality constraint. Since the sign of denominator might be either positive or negative, I couldn't move it to rhs. Maybe just keep it as it is and still try KKT

Comment: We have $ac-b^2\geqslant a_1\geqslant 1$ by the first constraint. But I'm not sure this implies that $a <a_1$.